# pointer and reference as arguments in function

Tags: c++

```
int* f(int* x) {
  (*x)++;
  return x; // Safe, x is outside this scope***
}

int& g(int& x) {
  x++; // Same effect as in f()
  return x; // Safe, outside this scope***
}

int& h() {
  int q;
//!  return q;  // Error
  static int x;
  return x; // Safe, x lives outside this scope
}

int main() {
  int a = 0;
  f(&a); 
  g(a);  
} ///:~
```

Sorry if my framing of the question is wrong or if my basic concepts are unclear.
This is a basic level doubt, but I didn't get anything regarding my doubt by googling.

Doubt: The above snippet (which i found on the net) has comments, /**/ Safe, x is outside this scope**  AND **// Safe, outside this scope**. I don't understand why those are safe and outside the scope. As far as I studied and understood, the arguments have a local scope, and that while function returns the control to call, local variables go out of scope (which makes it unsafe to return local variables). So, my question is why aren't they going out of scope AND why isn't it unsafe.

Comment: the actual variables inside the functions are going out of scope but the memory they refer to is not

Comment: @BeyelerStudios why is the memory not destroyed or freed. I mean when the function returns control, they are popped out of the stack, right?

Comment: But only *addresses* are popped, as `x` is a pointer / reference.

Comment: @leemes is right: the memory they refer to is `a` which is on the function stack in `main`

Comment: Okay! Now it is clear :) Thanks :)

Comment: The comments are somewhat misleading. The safety depends on the objects' lifetimes, not the scope of variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put in some comments for you below regarding how the variables are declared, and where they live in memory. I hope that helps explain how they are safe to return!

```
int* f(int* x) {
  (*x)++;
  return x; // Safe, x is outside this scope
}
```

This is safe because a pointer to x was passed in (a memory address). Since that is the case, it implies that this function did not declare the original variable,  and it came from out side of its scope.

```
int& g(int& x) {
  x++; // Same effect as in f()
  return x; // Safe, outside this scope
}
```

This is a similar scenario where the memory address of x was passed into the function and it was not declared in the scope of the function

```
int& h() {
  int q;
//!  return q;  // Error
  static int x;
  return x; // Safe, x lives outside this scope
}
```

This is also safe because a "static int x" is declared in the global pool of variables which means it lives on after the function is finished.

```
int main() {
  int a = 0;
  f(&a); 
  g(a);  
} ///:~
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int* f(int* x) {
  (*x)++;
  return x; ***// Safe, x is outside this scope***
}
```

In this case, it is only the pointer itself that is local to the function. The `int` that the pointer points at is not and is presumably created outside of this function. You are simply returning the pointer back out which continues to point at that object.

```
int& g(int& x) {
  x++; // Same effect as in f()
  return x; ***// Safe, outside this scope***
}
```

In this case, you are returning a reference to an `int` object that was also passed in to your function by reference. That object is therefore not local.

```
int& h() {
  int q;
//!  return q;  // Error
  static int x;
  return x; // Safe, x lives outside this scope
}
```

In this case, `x` is `static`, so it exists from the first time that declaration is encountered to the end of the program. It won't be destroyed at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Safe, x is outside this scope
```

This is directed at all the variables which are not local to function.

Your last case :-

```
int& h() {
  int q;
//!  return q;  // Error
  static int x;
  return x; // Safe, x lives outside this scope
}
```

Here you cannot return q, as q is local to function so when this function exits, q is also gone.

However, static local variable is safe to return as reference as this function doesn't limit scope of that variable.